# CSS Animation using Jquery and '.css'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I have a piece of code. The purpose is to play a selected animation from [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) on **click**.

**The code**

```
  $(".container>parent").click(function () {
    $('.element').css({
      'animation': 'fadeInUp .2s',
      '-webkit-animation': 'fadeInUp .2s'
    });
  });
```

**The problem**

Animation runs, but only one time. 'Infinite' attribute causes chaos :P

What else could I do, to play that animation every single time someone click it?

Thanks for your time.

**My HTML**:

```
            <span class="parent">
                <img src="assets/myimage.png" class="filter-image">
                <span class="element">Text</span>
            </span>
```

I want to animate the text everytime I click it.

Comment: Post your HTML, or make a jsfiddle

Comment: Propably because you didn't remove animation property after animation finishes

Comment: Hey, thanks and i am making a jsfiddle. But how to remove animation property after the animation finishes?

Comment: A better idea to me seems to add and remove a class and add it back again.

Comment: Thanks @BramVanroy for the suggestion, but the above way seems to work just fine. You said it for the sake of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".container>parent").click(function() {
    $('.element').css({
        'animation': 'fadeInUp .2s',
        '-webkit-animation': 'fadeInUp .2s'
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.element').removeAttr('style');
    },300);
});
```

Comment: You are the man! Totally understood my mistake. Case closed. Thank you and have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 0):

The animation won't work the second time if you don't remove animation class after the current animation finishes.

> But how to remove animation property after the animation finishes?

Here's a snippet:

```
var support = {};
support.animation = (function() {
    var animationEnd = (function() {
        var element = document.body || document.documentElement,
            animEndEventNames = {
                WebkitAnimation : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
                MozAnimation    : 'animationend',
                OAnimation      : 'oAnimationEnd oanimationend',
                animation       : 'animationend'
            }, name;

        for (name in animEndEventNames) {
            if (element.style[name] !== undefined) return animEndEventNames[name];
        }
    }());

    return animationEnd ? { end: animationEnd } : false;
})();



function animate(elem, cls, callback) {
    var $elem = $(elem);

    var onEndCallbackFn = function(ev) {
        if (support.animation) {
            $elem.removeClass(cls);
            this.removeEventListener(support.animation.end, onEndCallbackFn);
        }

        if (callback && typeof callback === 'function') { callback.call(this, ev); }
    };

    if (support.animation) {
        $elem.addClass(cls);
        $elem[0].addEventListener(support.animation.end, onEndCallbackFn);
    } else {
        onEndCallbackFn();
    }
}
```

usage is simple, just call animate function, like this:

```
animate($('.selector'), 'classWithAnimation', callbackFn);
```

In you case, you said you are using animate.css library:

```
$(".container>parent").click(function() {
    animate($('.element'), 'animated fadeInUp', function() {
        console.log('animation complete');
    );
});
```

Live example: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ey3o5zn2/)**