# Issue on Adding and Removing Animate Class to and item using Animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, animate.css

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0mxy2d1g/) and let me know how I can use the `.removeClass(animated fadeIn)` or add `fadeOut` class to the element after loading each item of the text array?

basically what I want to do is adding fade in and out for each element of array on appearing on the box `.changeText`

```
<div class="changeText" >Welcome</div>

<script>
$(function () {
    var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
    var counter = 0;
    setInterval(change, 3000);
    function change() {
     $(".changeText").html(text[counter]).addClass('animated fadeIn');
        counter++;
        if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe my recent answer to similar question will help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29445282/1451859

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` for this:

```
$(function () {
    var text = ["Welcome", "Hi", "Sup dude"];
    var counter = 0;
    setInterval(change, 3000);
    function change() {
        $(".changeText").fadeIn(500).html(text[counter]).fadeOut(500);
        counter++;
        if(counter >= text.length) { counter = 0; }
    }
});
```

**[Here is an Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0mxy2d1g/2/)**

---

Simply adjust the value of `500` to change the speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the animation bu using

```
$('#yourElement').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', doSomething);
```

It will trigger on animation is done.