# Run one jQuery function after another one finishes effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, timing

I've written the following two functions:

```
<script>          
$('.tile').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX",1000).promise().done(function () {
        $(".tile-group.six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    });
});
</script>
```

The first one performs a transition on some tiles that lasts about 3 seconds, and even though I have included .promise and .done the second function still loads the html page right away instead of waiting for the effect/transition to finish. I was thinking of using a setTimeinterval to make the second function wait until the first one finishes but I don't know how to use that to accomplish my desired behavior.

THE WHOLE CSS OF TRANSITIONS ON THE PAGE

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.animated.infinite {
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.animated.two {

    -webkit-animation-delay: 120ms; 
    animation-delay: 120ms;
}
.animated.three {
     -webkit-animation-delay: 320ms; 
    animation-delay: 320ms;
}
.animated.four {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 520ms; 
    animation-delay: 320ms;
}
.animated.five {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 720ms; 
    animation-delay: 720ms;
}
.animated.six {
     -webkit-animation-delay: 920ms; 
    animation-delay: 920ms;
}
.animated.seven {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1020ms; 
    animation-delay: 1020ms;
}
.animated.eight {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1220ms; 
    animation-delay: 1220ms;
}
.animated.nine {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1620ms; 
    animation-delay: 1620ms;
}
.animated.ten {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1820ms; 
    animation-delay: 1820ms;
}
.animated.eleven {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 2020ms; 
    animation-delay: 2020ms;
}
.animated.twelve {
      -webkit-animation-delay: 2220ms; 
    animation-delay: 2220ms;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }
}

@keyframes flipInX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  }

  60% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  80% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }
}

.flipInX {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInX;
  animation-name: flipInX;
}






/*CSS BIT FOR REVERSING THE ANIMATION ONCLICK EVENT 8*/


@-webkit-keyframes flipOutX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flipOutX {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px);
    transform: perspective(400px);
  }

  30% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.flipOutX {
  -webkit-animation-name: flipOutX;
  animation-name: flipOutX;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: what do you think that `1000` is doing with `addClass`?

Comment: no idea i shall get rid of it

Comment: I think there are two things being conflated here, the `1000` in `addClass` is an extension provided by [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/addClass/) it is used to define how long the animation to the class should take, however it appears here that the OP is using a CSS3 transition which JavaScript is unable to watch for the end event in this context.

Comment: right gotcha so in this case how do i get javascript to just simply wait for a few seconds before performing the second load function ?

Comment: I updated my answer to use transition end event.

Comment: @user3504751 check my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445014/css-animation-using-jquery-and-css/29445282#29445282

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple setTimeout can do the job. You can try this

```
<script>          
$('.tile').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".tile-group.six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    }, 1000);

});
</script>
```

Comment: Nice one that cracked it !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the jQueryUI `addClass` method supports promises, but you can use callbacks.

Also, you have to prevent the default action of the click event.

The equivilant of what you have is:

```
$('.tile').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX");
    $(".tile")[0].addEventListener("animationend", function() {
        $(".tile-group.six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    }, false);
});
```

Documentation for animation end event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend

Documentation for jQueryUI Add Class can be found at http://jqueryui.com/addClass/

Here is some information on the differences between `return false;` and `event.preventDefault();` https://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/

Comment: didn't work , it still isn't waiting for flipOutX to complete its transition ... the load needs to wait a few seconds

Comment: Are you including the jQueryUI library?

Comment: yup       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: @HJ05 class `.flipOutX` triggers animation not transition! so you have to bind animation end events

Comment: @CookieMan Thanks, I wrote that before the OP posted the full css code, I update my answer to align with the updates.

Comment: Note you may want to use JQuery's `once` method here to auto-remove the event listener when it happens. addEventListener will stick around and run the second time that `.tile` is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Better, but more time consuming:

Move transition animation into `jQuery.animate()`. You will have more control.

For example:

```
var css = {'height': '100%', opacity: 1};
var options = {
  duration: 3000,
  complete: function() {
    $(".tile-group.six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
  } 
};
$('.tile').on('click', function() {
  $(".tile").animate(css, options);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tile').on('click', function () {
         $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX", 1000, load )
});

  function load() {
    $(".tile-group.six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If `.tile` is a link, add `return false` to the end of your `click` event:

```
<script>          
$('.tile').on('click', function () {

    $(".tile").addClass("flipOutX",1000).promise().done(function () {
        $(".tile-group.six").load("musability-musictherapy-company-overview.html");
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
```